# Is it necessary to use gradle with roboelectric for android unit testing?

Tags: robolectric

I and my team have built up an android library project. it is built up on eclipse but we are using ant to build it. Presently we aren't using gradle. I have a roboelectric with dependencies jar file instead. But when I use this, while running the unit tests, the following error comes up

```
WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
[junit]          jar:file:/Users/prateekarora/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
[junit]      and jar:file:/Users/prateekarora/trunk/client/android/MCCMobileClient/test2/libs/robolectric-2.3-with-dependencies.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
```

When I remove the apache ant from eclipse's plugin folder, this stops working.
Can Anybody explain why this is happening?
Also, is it necessary to use roboelectric with gradle? If no, where can I find the roboelectric's jar files with/without dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to use gradle with robolectric. It is just about running specified java class (from junit) with proper classpath (including you source, test code and dependencies). Fixing your case is not something that is easy to make over stackoverflow (it will be some challenge even if you sit behind same computer).

Here are possible solutions:

1. Migrate your project build to the gradle
2. Keep using ant but move from dependency management from manuals jars to ivy
3. Keep using ant and manual jars dependency, but try to get robolectric.jar with all dependencies except ant one

The first one option is the easiest option as for me. It will require to change mindset a bit but this is officially only one supported build tool by Google as well there are a lot of examples and people that could help.

The second one also require you to learn how to use new tool. As well there less examples about ivy usage especially in android projects.

The third one will require to write custom script that removes ant from jar file or to rebuild robolectric-all.jar without one (ant) dependency. This will require to dive into maven build tool learning